# English prayers, mix in hebrew?

Tags: halacha, tefilla, hebrew, translation, language

Some prayers can be said in any language, and many people use the English translation in siddurim to daven directly, the question is is one allowed to mix in both hebrew and English when first learning, for example to say "boruch ata adonoi eloheinu melech haolam, who has made us holy with his commandments and commanded us regarding the washing of the hands"?

and other similar brochos, to start out in hebrew [if one understands only the beginning] then continue or conclude in English, regarding the parts one doesn't understand?

Same goes for verses, for example "adonai has ruled for all eternity"? can one say the hebrew names of G-d in the middle of praying in english, or does one have to say "lord", "G-d", etc.?

Comment: Great question. From the Igros Moshe Aruch Chaim 4, 70:4, it seems like it has to be either all English or all Lashon Hakodesh. However he doesn't explicitly mention this case

Comment: @Chatzkel interesting, I would be interested to know how this would work [all english] with the names of Hashem, which each have a specific kavana etc., or words like "boruch" which are pretty hard to translate etc.

Comment: I believe that's why lashon hakodesh is preferred, because of the letters and words have special meaning. But if your doing English then why would those be different

Comment: I checked the Artscroll siddur. On the first page in bold letters they write that in accordance with most poskim, when saying Hashem name, you should say either G-D, Lord, or Adonai, not Hashem which is what's actually written on the English side. So it seems that for Hashem name you can say it in Lashon hakodesh

Comment: @Chatzkel but can one say "Elo-heem" "Elo-haynu" etc.? or only Adonai? and what about the word "boruch"?

Comment: In Artscroll for Elokeinu they translate as our G-D and that's that. Only for Adon do they replace with Hashem and then say that when saying it you should say something else. For boruch what's wrong with blessed? The issue of us blessing vs G-D blessing is a kavana issue even in lashon hakodesh

Comment: @Chatzkel interesting, I wonder what the primary sources are or if there is any room for leniency, it could be artscroll was only following one opinion, also "blessed" could be mistaken for "thank you hashem", but Boruch is related to "hamavrich es hagefen" to draw down, and the idea of boruch is to draw down Hashem's energy into the world itself, and into the food one eats, which is only signified by the word boruch

Comment: I thought that normally we say that if you are praying by yourself then the prayers should be in *lashon ha'kodesh* because the *malachim* who take your prayers only understand *lashon ha'kodesh* whereas if you are praying with a *minyan* where the *shechinah* is present then you can pray in any language. If so, then when praying with a *minyan* it should make no difference if you mix English with *lashon ha'kodesh* as long as what you are saying makes some sort of sense?

Comment: @pcoz "makes some sort of sense" is key. Mixing languages every word is hardly considered speaking intelligibly. "American Yeshivish" mixes languages in a very specific way (a pidgin of sorts) and only something like that could possibly be allowed.

Comment: @DoubleAA https://www.yeshiva.org.il/ask/43302 יש תוספות במסכת עבודה זרה שמביאים מהירושלמי: "ודגלו עלי אהבה" – "ודלגו". זאת אומרת, שאפילו אם אדם טעה במשהו ולא ביטא מילים כמו שצריך בתפילה, ודאי שיוצא

Comment: @pcoz don't see how that's relevant

Comment: @DoubleAA If a *ba'al teshuva* wishes to express himself to Hashem as best as he is able, what greater ודלגו עלי אהבה can we have than that?

Comment: @pcoz I don't know, but again, I don't see how that is relevant. No on is making this ba'al teshuva speak a mix of languages that he'd have to speak them poorly. Pick your best language and use it as best you can, whether you are a baal teshuva or not.

Answer (score 3):

The Rambam in [Hilchos Tefilla 1:4](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Prayer_and_the_Priestly_Blessing.1.4?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) says:

> כֵּיוָן שֶׁגָּלוּ יִשְׂרָאֵל בִּימֵי נְבוּכַדְנֶצַּר הָרָשָׁע נִתְעָרְבוּ בְּפָרַס וְיָוָן וּשְׁאָר הָאֻמּוֹת וְנוֹלְדוּ לָהֶם בָּנִים בְּאַרְצוֹת הַגּוֹיִם וְאוֹתָן הַבָּנִים נִתְבַּלְבְּלוּ שְׂפָתָם וְהָיְתָה שְׂפַת כָּל אֶחָד וְאֶחָד מְעֹרֶבֶת מִלְּשׁוֹנוֹת הַרְבֵּה וְכֵיוָן שֶׁהָיָה מְדַבֵּר אֵינוֹ יָכוֹל לְדַבֵּר כָּל צָרְכּוֹ בְּלָשׁוֹן אַחַת אֶלָּא בְּשִׁבּוּשׁ שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר (נחמיה יג כד) ״וּבְנֵיהֶם חֲצִי מְדַבֵּר אַשְׁדּוֹדִית״ וְגוֹ׳‎ (נחמיה יג כד) ״וְאֵינָם מַכִּירִים לְדַבֵּר יְהוּדִית וְכִלְשׁוֹן עַם וְעַם״. וּמִפְּנֵי זֶה כְּשֶׁהָיָה אֶחָד מֵהֶן מִתְפַּלֵּל תִּקְצַר לְשׁוֹנוֹ לִשְׁאל חֲפָצָיו אוֹ לְהַגִּיד שֶׁבַח הַקָּדוֹשׁ בָּרוּךְ הוּא בִּלְשׁוֹן הַקֹּדֶשׁ עַד שֶׁיֵּעָרְבוּ עִמָּהּ לְשׁוֹנוֹת אֲחֵרוֹת. וְכֵיוָן שֶׁרָאָה עֶזְרָא וּבֵית דִּינוֹ כָּךְ עָמְדוּ וְתִקְּנוּ לָהֶם שְׁמוֹנֶה עֶשְׂרֵה בְּרָכוֹת עַל הַסֵּדֶר

> When the people of Israel went into exile in the days of the wicked Nebucednezzar, they mingled with the Persians, Greeks and other nations. In those foreign countries, children were born to them, whose language was confused. Everyone's speech was a mixture of many tongues. No one was able, when he spoke, to express his thoughts adequately in any one language, otherwise than incoherently, as it is said, "And their children spoke half in the speech of Ashdod and they could not speak in the Jews' language, but according to the language of each people" (Nehemiah 13:24). Consequently, when anyone of them prayed in Hebrew, he was unable adequately to express his needs or recount the praises of God, without mixing Hebrew with other languages. When Ezra and his Council realized this condition, they ordained the Eighteen Benedictions in their present order.

The [Einayim L'Mishpat in Brachos 40b](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=41031&st=&pgnum=41) understands from this Rambam that any mixing of languages is not allowed during prayers or blessings

Comment: but using only that language is OK? what about a word that has meaning both in english and hebrew, like "raid", could mean "descend" in hebrew or a group of people descending on their enemies? what about a name, like "yaakov", does one have to say "and he established it for Jacob as a decree" in davening, or is one allowed to say "Yaakov"? If one is allowed to say "Yaakov" instead of "Jacob" since its only a name, then what about the names of G-d? Is one allowed to say ad-nay, Elo-heem etc.? If not what's the difference between that and Yaakov and Jacob? is this only shmoneh esray or all parts

Comment: A name can't really be translated. Although it might have a meaning, when you say the name your referencing the person or place not the meaning. So Yackov is Yackov in all languages, you don't need to know any meaning (he held onto the ankle when he was born etc.). Hashem name is different obviously, as mentioned in previous comments, Artscroll seems to have different ways for different Names. Raid has different meanings so saying it in the wrong context obviously wouldn't work. Im not a rabbi, just my thoughts

Comment: "Hashem name is different obviously" why is it different? why is that obvious? " as mentioned in previous comments, Artscroll seems to have different ways for different Names." Im not talking about artscroll, Im talking about the primary sources of halacha

Comment: As for using only English, that's a huge debate dating back a few hundred years. The Chasam Sofer was strongly opposed when the question arose at the onset of Haskalah

Comment: well obviously some people approve of only english as people who dont know hebrew pray in english, the question is only for them who are anyways doing it only in english can they use the hebrew names? and the rambam source seems to imply only for shmoneh esray, but what about for the earlier prayers like hodu etc which is only pesukim, or what about blessings over food

Comment: Hashem name is not referring to a thing, it is referring to the meaning (Master of All, Is Was and Always will be, All Powerful etc.) Its not a regular Name.

Comment: every name has meaning but its also referencing a specific thing. hashem is not a thing, true, but in the context of names the names still refer to hashem, how is it any different?

Comment: I am not that well versed in the Names of Hashem, but one is supposed to have in mind the meaning when saying the Name. When you say the name Yitzchok you don't need to think about laughing.

Comment: OK, so why is that a reason to not say them? if anything, since u have to have in mind the meaning, how can one only pray in englsih, which would then remove all meanings from the names? and who's to say "Lord" is an accurate translation of Elo-heem anyways?

Answer (score 1):

B"H

I asked the OU and they said I can use hashem's hebrew names, here's a copy of the email text [earlier message at bottom]:

> The request (#90439) has been deemed solved.
>
> ---
>
> Jack Abramowitz, Aug 20, 2021, 11:15 EDT
>
> That's fine. In fact, according to some authorities, using God's
> Hebrew Nam= es even when praying in English would be preferred.
>
> Sincerely yours,
>
> Rabbi Jack Abramowitz OU Torah Content Editor facebook.com/outorah
> twitter.com/ou_torah
>
> ---
>
> Yaynikel, Aug 19, 2021, 18:51 EDT
>
> Hi if one is only praying in english, can he use the names of Hashem
> such as A= d-nay, El-heem etc. or does one have to say "lord", "G0d"
> etc>?
>
> User Browser: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64)
> AppleWebKit/537.36 = (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/*********
> Safari/537.36
>
> -------------------------------- This email is a service from The Orthodox Union Help Desk.

contact info:

> Jack Abramowitz (The Orthodox Union Help Desk)
> support@ou.zendesk.com reply-to:    The Orthodox Union Help Desk
> <support+id90439@ou.zendesk.com